# creating an instance of entity causes Reflect.getMetadata is not a function

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I started using typeorm. I have created some entities:

```
@Table()
export class User {
    @PrimaryColumn()
    name: string;
    @Column()
    passwordHash: string;
    @OneToMany(type => Sprint, sprint => sprint.scrumMaster)
    sprints: Sprint[];
    @OneToMany(type => BacklogItem, item => item.assignedTo)
    assignments: BacklogItem[];
    @OneToMany(type => BacklogItem, item => item.createdBy)
    createdItems: BacklogItem[];
}
@Table()
export class Sprint {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;
    @Column("date")
    start: Date;
    @Column("date")
    end: Date;
    @ManyToOne(type => User, user => user.sprints)
    scrumMaster: User;
    @OneToMany(type => BacklogItem, item => item.sprint)
    items: BacklogItem[];
    @Column()
    isFinished: boolean;
}
```

Typeorm creates the database (Sqlite) just fine. However, whenever I do create an instance of one of my entities, for example `let = user = new User()`, NodeJS instantly crashes with the following stacktrace:

```
C:\Users\Chris\Documents\TypeORM - Kopie (2)\node_modules\typeorm\decorator\columns\PrimaryColumn.js:20
    var reflectedType = ColumnTypes_1.ColumnTypes.typeToString(Reflect.getMetadata("design:type", object, propertyName));
                                                                       ^

TypeError: Reflect.getMetadata is not a function
at C:\Users\Chris\Documents\TypeORM - Kopie (2)\node_modules\typeorm\decorator\columns\PrimaryColumn.js:20:76
at __decorate (C:\Users\Chris\Documents\TypeORM - Kopie (2)\entities\Sprint.js:5:110)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Chris\Documents\TypeORM - Kopie (2)\entities\Sprint.js:19:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
at Module.load (module.js:456:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:415:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:407:3)
at Module.require (module.js:466:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

When I remove the line that creates the new instance, everything is fine again. I have tried to use different PrimaryKey decoraters like  `@PrimaryColumn("int", { generated: true })`, but this does not help.

EDIT: My tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.1",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [
            "es5",
            "es6"
        ],
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ]
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 12):

Make sure you are using TypeScript compiler version > 2.1 and you have enabled following settings in `tsconfig.json`:

```
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true
```

Also make sure you have imported reflect-metadata shim before any of your code with orm:

```
import "reflect-metadata";
```

Comment: I think I have everything. `tsc -version` gives me 2.1.4. I use `tsc -p .` to compile my code. I also added my tsconfig to the original post.

Comment: that should resolve your issue. Try to checkout this sample: https://github.com/typeorm/typescript-example run it and check if it works

Comment: The sample works indeed. I have now copied my entire source code into your sample and now it works. Thanks

Comment: Its working, but can you explain why this needs to be done ?

Comment: Important to note that the import "reflect-metadata" must be the first import statement before all other imports inside your index.ts file.

Comment: My issue was I had `import * as reflect from 'reflect-metadata';`. I needed just `import 'reflect-metadata';`.

Answer (score -2):

The sample [github.com/typeorm/typescript-example](http://github.com/typeorm/typescript-example) works fine for me. I have now copied my entire code into the example project and my issues are gone.

Comment: It is ok that the sample worked but that does not give any insight or clue of why the issue is happening to others trying to fix the same problem. So this remark could be an edit/remark to your question instead of an full answer.