# TypeError: Reflect.getMetadata is not a function

Tags: typescript, nestjs

here is the problem I encounter when I launch my nest server:

```
back-end/node_modules/@nestjs/common/decorators/core/optional.decorator.js:22
                const args = Reflect.getMetadata(constants_1.OPTIONAL_DEPS_METADATA, target) || [];
                                     ^

TypeError: Reflect.getMetadata is not a function
        at /Users/lucabento-versace/OneDrive-Ynov/Projets/3eme_annee/WEB/TrueEat/back-end/node_modules/@nestjs/common/decorators/core/optional.decorator.js:22:34
        at /Users/lucabento-versace/OneDrive-Ynov/Projets/3eme_annee/WEB/TrueEat/back-end/node_modules/@nestjs/common/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:104:41
        at Object.__decorate (/Users/lucabento-versace/OneDrive-Ynov/Projets/3eme_annee/WEB/TrueEat/back-
end/node_modules/@nestjs/common/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:99:99)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/lucabento-versace/OneDrive-Ynov/Projets/3eme_annee/WEB/TrueEat/back-end/node_modules/@nestjs/common/services/console-logger.service.js:204:43)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
        at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
        at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
```

I tested this in vain : `npm i reflect-metadata`
I have already looked at the questions about the same error but I can't find any solutions

Comment: Might be relevant - https://stackoverflow.com/a/41206392/1860540

Comment: Hello, I already have the config in the tsconfig.json

Comment: Did you import `reflect-metadata` as the first thing in your entry point?

Comment: In main.ts :`import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common/pipes/validation.pipe';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { DocumentBuilder, SwaggerModule } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import 'reflect-metadata';`

Comment: My issue was I had `import * as reflect from 'reflect-metadata';`. I needed just `import 'reflect-metadata';`.

Answer (score 13):

As user @hhearts already mentioned in the comment above, that's usually resolved by  importing "reflect-metadata" into the global namespace (then you only have to do it once.

But you can do it as scoped as you need it.

For (p)react you can do it for example as the first import in `App.ts`

```js
import "reflect-metadata";

export const App: FunctionalComponent = () => {
    (...)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

According to https://docs.typestack.community/typedi/v/develop/01-getting-started

Import the reflect-metadata package at the first line of your application:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
```

It works for me:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For me I changed `import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common/pipes'` to `import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common'` and it works now

Answer (score 2):

import `ValidationPipe` from `@nestjs/common/pipes` instead of `@nestjs/common/pipes/validation.pipe`

```
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common/pipes';
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to import `reflect-metadata` at the very beginning of your global file.